# Identifying uniqueness of multiple divs rendered by the for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, user-interface

The scenario is simple I am fetching the posts of different users & displaying on the home page just like facebook does. My app fires one ajax request receives json response [every post in the response has a unique post id] runs a for loop on it & renders multiple divs on the page.

I am using mustascheJS for client side templating.

Say the below is a template which gets appended to a container div for every iteration

```
<script  type="x-tmpl-mustache" id="todaysmoviescontainertemplate">
    <div id="movie_info" class="bg-default" style="display:table;width:100%;">
        <div style="display:table-row"> 
            <div style="display:table-cell;width:30%;"><a href=""><samp>{{movie}}</samp></a></div>
            <div style="display:table-cell;width:30%;">{{movieTime}} UTC | {{localTime}} your time</div>
            <div style="display:table-cell;width:10%;">{{movieStatus}}</div>
            <div style="display:table-cell;width:30%;">{{theatre}} theatre, {{location}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

ajax on success appends this template to a container div loaded with different data the number of times the loop runs.

Now the problem is I have n movie posts with the same div id `movie_info` with different data.

If I have to edit & update a particular movie post how do I edit that & send the changes to the server since all the template divs have the same id? How do I determine the uniqueness. Should I have a unique hidden field for every template div or something?

Comment: you should not have multiple elements with same id, id is supposed to be unique. Generate an unique id for each one or use a class. You don´t need a hidden field, you could store an unique identifier in data attribute

Comment: could you please elaborate a little more on storing a unique identifier in the data attribute.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: I would remove the `id` from the template and append it in the loop. Such that they are `.attr('id', 'movie_info-'+i);` etc. Since you have not included more code, it's hard to give you an example.

Comment: thnx I get an idea of it ..